# What is the cause of catastrophic backtracking for large decimal numbers in regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, python-re

I'm new to regular expressions and I've been working on a project using Python's re module and have needed to work with nested mathematical expressions.

This has been going relatively fine up until now, but I've noticed that floating numbers with nine or more decimal places (as strings) cause catastrophic backtracking when working with re.search().

For example, this line causes no issue.

```py
match = re.search(r"\(((?:[^()]+|R)+)\)", "(1.00000000+cos(1.0-3.0))")
```

However, this line does cause an issue.

```py
match = re.search(r"\(((?:[^()]+|R)+)\)", "(1.000000000+cos(1.0-3.0))")
```

For anyone wondering why I don't remove the first parentheses to remove the issue, note that this is an isolated set of lines: in the program, you may come across something like this:

```py
expression = "cos(tan(1)+sin(2)+tan(3)+sin(4)+tan(5))"
# during parsing, this becomes "cos(1.5574077246549023+0.9092974268256817+tan(3)+sin(4)+tan(5))"
# re.search(r"\(((?:[^()]+|R)+)\)", expression) would then cause a catastrophic backtrack
```

Comment: You are matching the `R` character, but recursion is not supported by python re. You can use the [regex pypi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) instead and write it as `\(((?:[^()]+|(?R))+)\)`

Comment: You'd really be better off using a simple tokeniser and then running the tokens through a parser. That's guaranteed linear time, and not too difficult to write (or you can use standard tools to generate it.) That aside, the question is interesting, but only if you modify it as per @Thefourthbird's comment so that it mentions the actual regular expression module you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Python `re` does not support recursion. But in your pattern you are using nested quantifiers with an `R` char in the alternation.

If the pattern can not match, it will try all permutations before failing causing catastrophic backtracking.

If you can make use of the [Python pypi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) you could recurse the whole pattern using `(?R)`

```
\(((?:[^()]+|(?R))+)\)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ceiwpe/1) with pcre selected that does support recursion.